# __eeprom and EEMEM

Tags: avr, iar, avr-gcc

I am trying to port a code base from iar to avr-gcc. Amongst other things that have to replaced, the iar eeprom memory attribute __eeprom has to replaced with a avr-gcc friendly attribute. AFAIK the replacement for that is EEMEM, but the usage differs and I am not able to figure out how to replace __eeprom in the cleanest manner.

```
../src/myfunc.h:35:46: error: section attribute not allowed for 'src'
     UBYTE *strcpye(UBYTE *dest, UBYTE EEMEM *src);
```

This error is not limited to pointers, but to all variables in general. IMO the usage of EEMEM is correct, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the avr-gcc toolchain, avr-libc defines macro `EEMEM` in `avr/eeprom.h`:

`#define EEMEM __attribute__((section(".eeprom")))`

This means it's just an attribute that determines the section in which an object with this attribute will be located. In particular, `EEMEM` only makes sense for variables in static storage. Moreover, accesses to  objects located in `EEMEM` have to be done by hand using functions / macros supplied by `avr/eeprom.h` like

```
void eeprom_read_block (void *dst, const void *src, size_t n);
void eeprom_write_byte (uint8_t *p, uint8_t value);
void eeprom_update_word (uint16_t *p, uint16_t value);
```

etc. Also notice that `EEMEM` is just an attribute and not a qualifier (like `__flash` for example).  This means that even though you can tag a pointer (target) using attributes, that won't change the access in any way. To  be more specific, any access through a pointer that's attributed `EEMEM` will be to **RAM** and not to eeprom.

In your case, the prototype of `strcpye` would read

`char* strcpye (char *dest, const char *src);`

and the implementation of that function would apply `eeprom_read_byte` on `src++` and write to `dest++` until it reads a terminal `\0`.  Notice that you might need an explicit pointer cast as `eeprom_read_byte` expects `[const] uint8_t*`, and that `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are 3 distinct types in C.

Comment: Does this mean that IAR allows non-global variable storage in eeprom? And avr-gcc does not?

Comment: I don't know IAR, but from the syntax it appears that `__eeprom` there acts like a qualifier (not an attribute like in gcc), i.e. accessing a location via such a pointer,  the compiler will generate code to operate on associated SFRs to perform EEprom accesses in a transparent manner. Notice that in that case, in `char __eeprom *src` the pointer **target** is accessed as EEprom, not `src`.

Comment: Thanks, it is much clearer now. The keyword definitely acts as a qualifier when used in function arguement or member of a struct context, but acts as an attribute in case of global variable declaration. The documentation is a bit unclear on the qualifier aspect.